# How to define a font without any variants in OpenType with CFF2 table

Tags: fonts, specifications, opentype

I would like to use the CFF2 table since it seems the most recent, as opposed to CFF. However, all the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff2) seem to only say how to define a font **with variants**. However, I don't want to have any variants of my font, at least at first, I just want 1 font, no variants. I'm wondering what I do in terms of leaving the tables out of the equation. The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff2#appendix-a-example-cff2-font) shows only how to do it with 1 or more variants. Wondering what to do.

Maybe I set the `VariationStore Data - length` to 0 and that's it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs page that you linked to, it seems pretty clear:

### Table 9 Top DICT Operator Entries

> The **`vstore`** operator and the data it points to are required if variation data is present, *and must be omitted if there is no varation data*.

So, don't put a `vstore` operator into topDICT.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not creating a variable font (no vstore), then there's no significant benefit of using a CFF2 table rather than a CFF table: the CFF2 table is basically an extension of the CFF table that adds ability to store glyph variation data. There was some cleanup of legacy cruft along the way, but that doesn't make any functional difference.